# Unable to resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' when using 'update' command in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

When I use the command "sudo apt-get update" I get the following errors:

```
   Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
     Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
   Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   Reading package lists... Done
   W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic      /InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
   W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Could you please help me to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

check your `/etc/resovl.conf` & send the result

Comment: nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/etc/resolv.conf" 18 lines, 715 characters

Comment: add  nameserver 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to remove the `us` from the entry for
`archive.ubuntu.com` in /etc/apt/sources.list.